# Dynamic CTE's as part of a SProc in DB2/400

Tags: sql, dynamic, common-table-expression, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm trying to write a SProc in db2/400 in a V7R2 environment which creates a CTE based on the parameters passed.  I then need to perform a recursive query on the CTE.

I'm running issues into creating and executing the dynamic CTE.

According to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzpreph2.htm 
the `prepare` statement does not work with the `WITH` or `SELECT` statements directly.

I tried to wrap both the dynamic CTE and dynamic `SELECT` in a `VALUES INTO` and manage to successfully prepare the statement.  The issue then comes when I try to execute the statement.

I get an error code of `SQL0518` which is defined here (CTRL+F for 'SQL0518' to jump down): http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzala/rzalamsg.html (NOTE*: This link is for V5R2 but the error code and text portion of my error is exact to the error listed here with the same code.  So I'm sure the error code remained the same between versions)

From the 3 recovery suggestions listed, the second seems unlikely to be the case since my `execute` is the very next line after my `prepare`.  Suggestion 3 also seems unlikely because there is no use of `commit` or `rollback`.  So I am inclined to believe suggestion 1 applies to my particular case.  However, I do not understand how to take the suggested steps.

> If &1 identifies a prepared SELECT or DECLARE PROCEDURE statement, a different prepared statement must be named in the EXECUTE statement.

Am I supposed to have two prepare statements for the same execute?  Syntactically how would this look?

Here is the code for my SProc for reference:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DLLIB/G_DPIVOT@ ( 
    IN TABLE_NAME CHAR(12) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
    IN PIVOT CHAR(12) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
    IN PIVOTFLD CHAR(12) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
    IN "VALUE" DECIMAL(10, 0) DEFAULT  0  , 
    INOUT LIST CHAR(5000) CCSID 37 ) 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC DLLIB/G_DPIVOT@ 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    BEGIN 

DECLARE STMT1 VARCHAR ( 1000 ) ; 
SET STMT1 = 'WITH DETAILS ( ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' , ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' , CURR , PREV ) AS ( ' || 
    'SELECT ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ,' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ',' || 
        ' ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ORDER BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' ) AS CURR ,' || 
        ' ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ORDER BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' ) - 1 AS PREV' || 
    ' FROM ' || TRIM ( TABLE_NAME ) || 
    ' WHERE ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' = ' || TRIM ( VALUE ) || 
    ' GROUP BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' , ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' )' || 
    ' VALUES( SELECT MAX ( TRIM ( L '','' FROM CAST ( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ( ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' , '','' ) AS CHAR ( 5000 ) ) ) )' || 
    ' FROM DETAILS ' || 
    ' START WITH CURR = 1 ' || 
    ' CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' = PRIOR ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' AND PREV = PRIOR CURR) INTO ?' ; 


--SET LIST = STMT1;     -- If I execute the value of LIST in interactive SQL everything is as expected (minus the VALUES INTO ofcourse)
PREPARE S1 FROM STMT1 ; 
EXECUTE S1 USING LIST;      -- If I comment this I don't get an error, but I also don't get a return value in LIST)

END  ;
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: I am trying to create a SProc (which I will use to create a UDF) which has 5 parameters.  I am trying to pivot a single field spanning across multiple records so the values are returned as a comma delimited string.  I want to make this dynamic though so I can re-use it for many situations.  An example call would be: `CALL DLLIB.G_DPIVOT@(TABLE, PIVOT, PIVOTFLD, VALUE, LIST);` Where `TABLE` is the name of the table I want to pivot, `PIVOT` is the commonality between records (FK), `PIVOTFLD` is the field I want to condense to a single string, `VALUE` is the FK value I want to use to pivot on, and `LIST` is the OUT parameter which would contain the resulting string.  You can read more about a non-dynamic implementation here: http://www.mcpressonline.com/sql/techtip-combining-multiple-row-values-into-a-single-row-with-sql-in-db2-for-i.html

The use is for when I have a header table which has a one-to-many relationship with another table.  I'll then be able to summarize all the values of a particular field in the "many" table based on the PK/FK relationship.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a recent attempt which I think I manage to successfully create the CTE using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and am now trying to just perform a simple select on it.  I'm trying to make use of DB2 cursors but get at error at the "C2" on the line `DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR S2;`.  I don't have much experience with DB2 cursors but believe I am using them in the correct way.

```
DECLARE STMT1 VARCHAR ( 1000 ) ; 
DECLARE STMT2 VARCHAR ( 1000 ) ; 
SET STMT1 = 'WITH DETAILS ( ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' , ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' , CURR , PREV ) AS ( ' || 
    'SELECT ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ,' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ',' || 
    ' ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ORDER BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' ) AS CURR ,' || 
    ' ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ORDER BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' ) - 1 AS PREV' || 
    ' FROM ' || TRIM ( TABLE_NAME ) || 
    ' WHERE ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' = ' || TRIM ( VALUE ) || 
    ' GROUP BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' , ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' )';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT1;

SET STMT2 = "SELECT * FROM DETAILS";

PREPARE S2 FROM STMT2; 
DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR S2;
OPEN C2;
FETCH C2 INTO LIST;
CLOSE C2;
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with these changes?

Here is the exact error message (excluding suggestion text):

```
SQL State: 42601
Vendor Code: -104
Message: [SQL0104] Token C2 was not valid. Valid tokens: GLOBAL.
```

**EDIT 3 (Final SProc):**
@user2338816 for all of the help.  See his post for an explanation of the solution, but here is the final SProc for reference:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DLLIB/G_DPIVOT@ ( 
    IN TABLE_NAME CHAR(12) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
    IN PIVOT CHAR(12) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
    IN PIVOTFLD CHAR(12) CCSID 37 DEFAULT  ''  , 
    IN "VALUE" DECIMAL(10, 0) DEFAULT  0  , 
    INOUT LIST CHAR(5000) CCSID 37 ) 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC DLLIB/G_DPIVOT@ 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    CONCURRENT ACCESS RESOLUTION DEFAULT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    BEGIN 

DECLARE STMT1 VARCHAR ( 1000 ) ; 
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1 ; 

SET STMT1 = 'WITH DETAILS ( ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' , ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' , CURR , PREV ) AS ( ' || 
    'SELECT ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ,' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ',' || 
        ' ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ORDER BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' ) AS CURR ,' || 
        ' ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' ORDER BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' ) - 1 AS PREV' || 
    ' FROM ' || TRIM ( TABLE_NAME ) || 
    ' WHERE ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' = ' || TRIM ( VALUE ) || 
    ' GROUP BY ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' , ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' )' || 
    ' SELECT MAX ( TRIM ( L '','' FROM CAST ( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ( ' || TRIM ( PIVOTFLD ) || ' , '','' ) AS CHAR ( 5000 ) ) ) ) ' || 
    ' FROM DETAILS ' || 
    ' START WITH CURR = 1 ' || 
    ' CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' = PRIOR ' || TRIM ( PIVOT ) || ' AND PREV = PRIOR CURR' ; 

PREPARE S1 FROM STMT1 ; 
OPEN C1 ; 
FETCH C1 INTO LIST ; 
CLOSE C1 ; 

END  ;
```

Comment: You've including links to manuals for v5r4 and v5r2.   Neither of which support recursive CTE; which came out in  v 7.1 .  What OS release are you actually on?

Comment: V7R2. I apologize, I did not realize those links were for previous versions.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I am trying to create a SProc (which I will use to create a UDF) which has 5 parameters.  I am trying to pivot a single field spanning across multiple records so the values are instead a comma delimited list in a single field.  I want to make this dynamic though so I can re-use it for many situations.  An example call would be: CALL DLLIB.G_DPIVOT@(TABLE, PIVOT, PIVOTFLD, VALUE, LIST);  You can read more about it here: http://www.mcpressonline.com/sql/techtip-combining-multiple-row-values-into-a-single-row-with-sql-in-db2-for-i.html

Comment: I updated the question with more elaboration on my intentions for usage.

Comment: It seems as though the prepare is failing, but guessing you don't see an error in the joblog.  Might try checking SQLCODE/SQLSTATE or using GET DIAGNOSTICS after the prepare.

Comment: Well I do see an error in the job log.  It is "Prepared statement S1 not found."  But I only get that error if I include the `Execute` statement.  If I comment that out then there is no error.   The SQLSTATE is 07003, VENDOR CODE is -518 and the SQLCODE is SQL0518.  When I check out the SQLCODE at the link in my question all of the error messages match up.  I just don't know why `S1` wouldn't exist. If the `Prepare` fails wouldn't it throw an error regardless if I comment/un-comment the `Execute` statement?  I'm fairly new to AS/400 so I will start reading up on how to use `GET DIAGNOSTICS`.

Comment: @Charles Note that recursive CTE queries became [available in V5R4.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/sqlp/rbafyrecursivequeries.htm?lang=en)

Comment: @user2338816...good catch...it was only the `CONNECT BY` clause for RCTE added at 7.1.

Comment: you should return a table of the common field first procedure.  2nd procedure table to csv.

Comment: I had attempted that already, but when I try to `prepare` the statement which just contains the CTE It fails when calling the SProc with an error of `SQL0104`.  If I add `SELECT * FROM DETAILS` to the end of the statement (immediately after the CTE) it no longer fails on the `prepare` but instead on the `execute` with the error already mentioned.  I don't think you can run a CTE without performing any actions on it because when I attempt to do so interactively (not in the SProc) I get the same error.

Comment: declare pivotV varchar(100);   set pivotV  = trim(pivot);     Now use pivotV instead of all the trim(privot) when your building your statement to execute.

Comment: Thank you I will do that, it would make everything more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is in the EXECUTE. You can't "execute" the prepared SELECT. Instead, you'll need to DECLARE CURSOR for S1 and FETCH rows from the CURSOR. Note that 'executing' a SELECT statement wouldn't actually do anything if it was allowed; it would just "SELECT", so EXECUTE doesn't make much sense. (A SELECT INTO statement can be different, but it's not clear if that's appropriate here.)

It might be possible to OPEN a CURSOR and return a result set rather than FETCHing rows. With more definition of how you actually want to use this, some elaboration should be possible.

**Edit:**

Second problem:

I've created more readable versions of your original CTE and the CTE in your edited question. The original:

```
WITH DETAILS ( PIVOT , PIVOTFLD , CURR , PREV ) AS ( 
    SELECT PIVOT , PIVOTFLD ,
         ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PIVOT ORDER BY PIVOTFLD ) AS CURR ,
         ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PIVOT ORDER BY PIVOTFLD ) - 1 AS PREV
    FROM TABLE_NAME 
    WHERE PIVOT = VALUE 
    GROUP BY PIVOT , PIVOTFLD )
    VALUES( SELECT MAX ( CAST ( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH ( PIVOTFLD , ',' ) AS CHAR ( 5000 ) ) ) )
    FROM DETAILS 
    START WITH CURR = 1 
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PIVOT = PRIOR PIVOT AND PREV = PRIOR CURR) INTO ? ;
```

You have a VALUE INTO statement after the CTE. AFAIK, that's not valid.

And your edited example:

```
WITH DETAILS ( PIVOT , PIVOTFLD , CURR , PREV ) AS (  
     SELECT  PIVOT ,
             PIVOTFLD ,
            ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PIVOT ORDER BY PIVOTFLD ) AS CURR , 
            ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PIVOT ORDER BY PIVOTFLD ) - 1 AS PREV
     FROM TABLE_NAME 
     WHERE PIVOT = VALUE 
     GROUP BY PIVOT , PIVOTFLD );
```

Well, it's just a bare CTE that has no associated SELECT referencing it. You do try to PREPARE a SELECT statement later, but the two need to go together. You can't EXECUTE the CTE by itself.

Try putting them together as a single statement and see if a CURSOR creates over the result. Variable STMT1 would then look something like this:

```
WITH DETAILS ( PIVOT , PIVOTFLD , CURR , PREV ) AS (  
     SELECT  PIVOT ,
             PIVOTFLD ,
            ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PIVOT ORDER BY PIVOTFLD ) AS CURR , 
            ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY PIVOT ORDER BY PIVOTFLD ) - 1 AS PREV
     FROM TABLE_NAME 
     WHERE PIVOT = VALUE 
     GROUP BY PIVOT , PIVOTFLD )
SELECT * FROM DETAILS ;
```

Note that the statement includes the SELECT at the end. The `WITH ...` clause is followed by the `SELECT ...` in a **single statement** that is PREPAREd. The CURSOR would then be OPENed over that statement.

**Edit 2:**

I have modified a sample CTE that I've had for a while to fit into a stored proc and to return a value. It was compiled and run on my i 6.1 system. The CTE is PREPAREd from a string placed into a VARCHAR, then a CURSOR is opened over it. Rows are FETCHed in a WHILE-loop.

The CTE generates summary rows that are then UNIONed with detail rows from QIWS/QCUSTCDT. The summary is by STATE to provided a sub-total of BALDUE. The WHILE-loop is kind of meaningless; it only shows FETCHing and processing of rows. The only action is to count the number of rows that **are not** summary rows out of the CTE. This is essentially the same as the number of rows in the base table. The row count is returned in the rowCnt OUT parameter.

The source code is copy/pasted, but comes from two sources. First, the CREATE PROCEDURE statement is taken from iNavigator's 'Run SQL scripts' utility after generating the SQL from the compiled stored procedure. And second, the BEGIN ... END compound statement body is from the original I typed into the iNavigator New-> Procedure function. Although the two would have logical equivalence, I wanted to preserve the actual lines that were input. You can copy/paste the entire source into 'Run SQL Scripts' or go through the utility to create the procedure and only copy/paste the BEGIN ... END compound statement after entering values into the first two tabs of the New-> Procedure function.

I have a schema named SQLEXAMPLE that I build things like this into. You'll need to adjust the schema and procedure names to fit your environment. The QIWS/QCUSTCDT table should exist on nearly all AS/400-series systems.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SQLEXAMPLE.CTE_CustCDT ( 
    OUT rowCnt INTEGER ) 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC SQLEXAMPLE.CTECUSTCDT 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    CLOSQLCSR = *ENDMOD , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX 

 BEGIN 

 DECLARE sumRows INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ; 

 DECLARE cusNum INTEGER ; 
 DECLARE lstNam CHAR(10) ; 
 DECLARE state CHAR(2) ; 
 DECLARE balDue DECIMAL(7, 2) ; 

 DECLARE stmt1 VARCHAR(512) ; 

 DECLARE at_end INT DEFAULT 0 ;

 DECLARE not_found
    CONDITION FOR '02000';
 DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR c1Stmt ; 
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not_found
    SET at_end = 1 ;


 SET stmt1 = 'with t1 As(
                 SELECT 0 ,''Tot'' , state , sum( balDue ) 
                     FROM qiws.qcustcdt 
                     GROUP BY state 
                     ORDER BY state
                                     ) 
        select cusNum , lstNam , state, balDue 
            from qiws.qcustcdt
       union 
        select *
            from t1 
            order by state FOR FETCH ONLY' ; 

 PREPARE c1Stmt FROM stmt1 ;
 OPEN c1 ;

 FETCH C1 INTO cusNum , lstNam , state  , balDue ;

 WHILE at_end = 0 DO

    IF cusNum <> 0 THEN SET sumRows = sumRows + 1 END IF ; 

    FETCH C1 INTO cusNum , lstNam , state  , balDue ;

 END WHILE ; 

 SET rowCnt = sumRows ;

 CLOSE c1 ;

 END
```

When the CTE is run by itself in STRSQL, the first few lines of output look like this:

```
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+.
        CUSNUM   LSTNAM    STATE                                     BALDUE 
       475,938   Doe        CA                                       250.00 
             0   Tot        CA                                       250.00 
       389,572   Stevens    CO                                        58.75 
             0   Tot        CO                                        58.75 
       938,485   Johnson    GA                                     3,987.50 
             0   Tot        GA                                     3,987.50 
       846,283   Alison     MN                                        10.00 
       583,990   Abraham    MN                                       500.00 
             0   Tot        MN                                       510.00
```

The summary rows should easily be recognized. And when the stored proc is CALLed from 'Run SQL Scripts', the resulting output is:

```
Connected to relational database TISI on Tisi as Toml - 090829/Quser/Qzdasoinit

> call SQLEXAMPLE.CTE_CustCDT( 0 )

Return Code = 0

Output Parameter #1 = 12

Statement ran successfully   (570 ms)
```

The QIWS/QCUSTCDT table on that system has 12 rows, and that matches the value returned.

It's not exactly the same as your desired CTE, but it should demonstrate that a dynamic CTE can be used. It also shows how FETCHes might pull rows from the CTE for whatever purpose is needed.

Comment: I eliminated the `EXECUTE` statement and replaced it with `DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;` but am getting an error at `C1`.  The error code is `SQL0104`.  I actually am trying to use a `VALUES INTO` clause on my select.  It is returning a single field and I am trying to get that field into the variable `LIST`.  So if that is a possible method which would work I'd like to know how I am doing it wrong.  I just tried `SELECT INTO` and am still getting the same behavior.  I had trouble before when I tried this, but should I separate my CTE definition into 1 statement and my select into a second?

Comment: I modified "STMT1" to include the `SELECT * FROM DETAILS;` and then followed with this portion of code `DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
PREPARE S1 FROM STMT1;
OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO LIST;
CLOSE C1;`  Am I declaring the cursor and preparing it correctly?  I am back to the error `Message: [SQL0104] Token C1 was not valid. Valid tokens: GLOBAL.`  I am trying to base my cursor declaration off of this site: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7462.cursors-open-close-and-fetch.aspx.  Thank you for all of your help so far.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I kept trying to prepare my statement and then declare the cursor.  It had to be the other way around, now I know so thank you again.